# Call Of Non function error

Tags: c, file-io

Hello friends i am new to C language
I am getting an error in my program(in turbo c compiler)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    FILE *fopen().*p;//error call of nonfunction
    char name[10];

    p=fopen("rec.dat","r");
    printf("enter your name:");
    scanf("%s",name);
    fprintf("p,"my name is %s",name);
    fclose(p);
    getch();
}
```

i would be happy if someone look at my problem and give some solution..

Answer (score 4):

The code you posted most likely isn't the same code you compiled. You should have gotten a number of syntax error messages, which you didn't mention. Look for mismatched quotation marks.

Your line:

```
FILE *fopen().*p;
```

was probably intended to be:

```
FILE *fopen(),*p;
```

That would declare both the `fopen()` function and the `FILE*` object `p`. But it's completely unnecessary to declare `fopen` yourself; that's what the `#include <stdio.h>` is for. So just change it to

```
FILE *p;
```

While you're at it, change `void main()` to `int main(void)`, and get rid of whatever book told you that `void main()` is correct.

And `scanf("%s",name);` is unsafe. It will read as many a space-delimited sequence of characters into `name`. The problem is, you haven't told `scanf` how big `name` is. If I type 20 characters, `scanf` will write past the end of `name`. Hilarity will ensue.

Answer (score 1):

The error line should be like this:

```
FILE *p = fopen("rec.dat", "r");
// remove the subsequent call of fopen below
```

or just

```
FILE *p;
// Keep the fopen call below
```

Comment: No, it shouldn't. That line attempts to *declare* both the `fopen` function and the `FILE*` object `p`.

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `FILE *p;`? There's a proper `fopen` call just below.